# Email cancelled Error handler

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba

i have a button the email a FILTERED REPORT named EngdetailRpt and it works great if the email is actually sent.
However if for some reason the email is cancelled from outlook, i get an error and the next time i try to send a filtered report it sends the same filter as last time or locks up the database completely.
can anyone suggest handler code that will prevent these error.

below is my current code,

```
Private Sub cmdEmail_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdEmail_Click_Err

    'opens report (hidden) based on Current Form view
    DoCmd.OpenReport "EngDetailRpt", acViewPreview, "", "[TAG_NAME]='" & Me!TAG_NAME & "'", acHidden
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "EngDetailRpt", acFormatPDF
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "EngDetailRpt", acSaveNo

cmdEmail_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdEmail_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "EngDetailsFrm", acSavePrompt
    Resume cmdEmail_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: It kind of depends on why the error is happening. Initially, I would recommend changing the msgbox in the error handler to: MsgBox Err.Description,, "cmdEmail_Click: " & err.Number . This will give you the error number in the title bar of the message box when there is an error. Then you can use that error number to either a) research and fix, or b) do an select case err.number code block, and have custom error handling for just that one error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the clean-up code (closing the hidden report) still runs, even after an error.

In cases like this I prefer to use "inline" error handling, like this:

```vb
'opens report (hidden) based on Current Form view
DoCmd.OpenReport "EngDetailRpt", acViewPreview, "", "[TAG_NAME]='" & Me!TAG_NAME & "'", acHidden

' inline error handling
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "EngDetailRpt", acFormatPDF
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Runtime-Error " & Err.Number & " on SendObject"
End If
On Error GoTo cmdEmail_Click_Err

DoCmd.Close acReport, "EngDetailRpt", acSaveNo
```

Comment: almost there, it works fist time, but if i cancel a future email, it freezes again.  almost there i think